# Optional parameter and clausule .where

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, angularfire2

I'm using `angularcli` and `angularfire2`, my app have a method with optional parameter for to retrieve data in `firestore`.

```
buildWomen(id: string, sex?: string, age?: string): Observable<Humans[]> {
    this.humanCollec = this.db.collection('human/' + id + '/women', ref => ref
      .where('sex', '==', sex) //--this can be null
      .where('age', '==', age); //--this can be null
    return this.humamObersArray = this.humanCollec.valueChanges();
  }
```

I'm showing only 2 parameters for simplify this example but in real method I have 10 parameters. There is a the best way for check it or ignore **.where** clausule when last parameter is `null`

**UPDATE**:

**...service.ts**

```
...
humanCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<Human>;
humanObersArray: Observable<Human[]>;
...
buildHuman(id: string, sex?: string, age?: string, ethnicity?: string, height?: string, weight?: string, religion?: string){ //: Observable<Human[]>
      //this.humanCol = 

      this.db.collection('human/'+id+'/women', ref => {
      let retVal = ref as any;
      if (sex != null) { retVal = retVal.where('sex', '==', sex) }
      if (age != null) { retVal = retVal.where('age', '==', age) }
      if (ethnicity != null) { retVal = retVal.where('ethnicity', '==', ethnicity) }
      if (height != null) { retVal = retVal.where('height', '==', height) }
      if (weight != null) { retVal = retVal.where('weight', '==', weight) }
      if (religion != null) { retVal = retVal.where('religion', '==', religion) }

      return retVal;
      //return this.humanObersArray = this.humanCol.valueChanges();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build on the ref within the factory, checking for the presence of the parameters:

```
this.humanCollec = this.db.collection(`human/${id}/women`, ref => {
  let retVal = ref as any;
  if (sex != null) { retVal = retVal.where('sex', '==', sex) }
  if (age != null) { retVal = retVal.where('age', '==', age) }
  ...
  return retVal;
});
```

Comment: This way is very better. But, whats about: "Query type cannot be assigned to type 'Collection Reference'." Error showing in  { retVal =  I try: let retVal: Query = ref but not working, and try remove this.humanCollec , but not working too.

Comment: That's probably just the type system upset that you're reassigning retVal as a different type. Cast retVal as any (or technically CollectionReference | Query)

Comment: Edited my answer to take that into account.