# Convert CollectionReference in AngularFirestoreCollection<T> or Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50930604/optional-parameter-and-clausule-where) is returning a `CollectionReference`. 
However, this method used to return a `AngularFirestoreCollection<myObj>` before I converted it to `Observable<myObj[]>` to work with arrays.

```
humanCol : AngularFirestoreCollection<Human>;
humanObersArray: Observable<Human[]>;

constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }
```

**Before I was using this way. Work greats to fetch all data.**

```
buildHuman(): Observable<Human[]> {
   this.humanCol = this.db.collection('path');
   return this.humanObersArray = this.humanCol.valueChanges();
}
```

**Now, I use have optional parameters.**

```
buildHuman(param1: string, param2?: string, param3?: string...){ 
  this.db.collection('path', ref => {
  let retVal = ref as any;
  if (param1 != null) { retVal = retVal.where('param1', '==', param1) }
  if (param2 != null) { retVal = retVal.where('param2', '==', param2) }
  if (param3 != null) { retVal = retVal.where('param3', '==', param3) }
  ...
  return retVal; //this return a CollectionReference 
  });
}
```

How I can to convert `retVal` to `AngularFirestoreCollection<T>` or `Observable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `buildHuman` doesn't return anything. Just return the `this.db.collection` call and you get a `AngularFirestoreCollection`. Or add call `valueChanges` like before to get an `observable`:

```
buildHuman(param1: string, param2?: string, param3?: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref => {
        let retVal = ref as any;
        if (param1 != null) { retVal = retVal.where('param1', '==', param1); }
        if (param2 != null) { retVal = retVal.where('param2', '==', param2); }
        if (param3 != null) { retVal = retVal.where('param3', '==', param2); }
        return retVal;
    });
}
```

OR

```
buildHuman(param1: string, param2?: string, param3?: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref => {
        let retVal = ref as any;
        if (param1 != null) { retVal = retVal.where('param1', '==', param1); }
        if (param2 != null) { retVal = retVal.where('param2', '==', param2); }
        if (param3 != null) { retVal = retVal.where('param3', '==', param2); }
        return retVal;
    })
    .valueChanges();
}
```