# collection reference cast to angularfirestorecollection or observable

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, observablecollection, angularfire2

I have below code

**service file datalink**

```
private dbUser = '/users';
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
this.userCollection = firestore.collection(this.dbUser);
}
```

In my component file

```
this.datalink.userCollection .ref.where("name","==","xxx").orderBy("updatedOn")
```

it returns CollectionReference,

How to Convert CollectionReference in AngularFirestoreCollection or Observable?

I got below link

[Convert CollectionReference in AngularFirestoreCollection<T> or Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158991/convert-collectionreference-in-angularfirestorecollectiont-or-observable)

But not able to convert my scenario, lack of knowledge being new in the era.

I know I can do this like below which returns per my requirement.

```
this.firestore.collection('collectionanme',ref)
```

But I want my above query to return AngularFirestoreCollection or Observable?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show more code? Specifically your constructor, where you're setting `dblist` and where you're trying to return the collection/observable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return an AngularFirestoreCollection or an Observable, do this:

```ts
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

export class MyClass {    
  dblist: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.dblist = this.afs.collection<any>('path/to/collection', ref => {
      return ref.where("name","==","DAL").orderBy("updatedOn");
    });
  }

  getCollection(): AngularFirestoreCollection<any> {
    return this.dblist;
  }

  getObservable(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.dblist.valueChanges();
    // or return this.dblist.snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can see I said I am doing this way in my project, But I want to improve the structure of project, and instead giving the collection directly, I want to give reference of collection, Please go through once more my post

Comment: I can not see where you said/showed you were doing it this way. You say "it returns CollectionReference" and "I want to give reference of collection". If you want to return a reference and it's currently returning a reference, then what is the problem?

Comment: sorry for confusion. "I know I can do this like below which returns per my requirement.

this.firestore.collection('collectionanme',ref)"

Comment: I just need collectionrefrence to cast as observable or angularfirestorecollection

Comment: I don't think you can cast a reference to a collection or an observable. I checked a bunch of official documentation and couldn't find anything on casting a CollectionReference. Maybe you're running into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your use case?

Comment: I have created a service which is the only endpoint for the app to communicate with firestore. and every component uses the references to collections defined in that service. No need to include angularfire package in each component.

Comment: for example ----  private dbUser = '/users';
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
this.userCollection = firestore.collection(this.dbUser);
} --- the userCollection is refereing the the user collection, so whereever we need to use the user collection we do not need to use like this.firestore.collection("user",'ref')....

Comment: we just call this.dbcollectoin.usercollection which is actually refering the user collection.

Answer (score -1):

private dbUser = '/users';
    user:any; Declare observable
    constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
        this.user();
    }
    user(){
        this.user = this.firestore.collection('Users',ref 
        =>ref.where('name','==', 'xyz' )).valueChanges();
    }

Comment: I mentioned this syntax in my post, that I am able to get, I want to cast collection reference to observale

Comment: I said that is also working for me, but check your code, you are giving collection name. this.firestore.collection('collectionanme',ref) this way. I am not asking this way. please go through once more my post